# Nodejs image not converting to base64 correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, base64

So i'm reading a file, and saving the file into a variable. I then create a buffer using the variable and convert it to a base64 string, to display in an `<img>` element. But when its generated it dosen't look like a base64 string, and it dosen't display on the page.

I am reading the png file using `fflate`

```
    async readFile (name: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const file = this.getFile(name);
            if (!file) return resolve(null);
    
            const filedata: string[] = [];
            const decoder = new DecodeUTF8();
            file.ondata = (err, data, final) => {
                decoder.push(data, final);
            }
            decoder.ondata = (str, final) => {
                filedata.push(str);
                if (final) resolve(filedata.join(''));
            }
            file.start();
        })
    }
```

```
const avatar = await readFile('avatar.png');
const avatar_64 = Buffer.from(avatar).toString('base64');
console.log(avatar);
console.log(avatar_64)
```

```html
<img alt="User Avatar" src={`data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,${avatar_64}`}/>
```

[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjvVA.png)

Is this how it's supposed to look? I've already tried putting the charset into the img uri, but that dosen't seem to work

Comment: what's the other `{}` are for?

Comment: @Michael you mean next to `src`? I'm using react, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it works with this png file : (https://flatbay.fr/img/seloger.png)

```
let avatar = require('fs').readFileSync('./seloger.png');
const avatar_64 = Buffer.from(avatar).toString('base64');
// console.log(avatar);
// console.log(avatar_64)
console.log('<img alt="User Avatar" src="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,'+avatar_64+'"/>');
```

Can you try with my picture ? or give me yours ?
Or maybe the way you get avatar populated is the problem ?

the fact that u use react should not be a problem IMHO. syntax looks valid.

Comment: I still get the same issue, it might be how I'm reading it. I'm not using `fs`. I'll edit my original message.

Comment: I see, you should not decode your binary data to utf8. it breaks the data.

Comment: That seems to have bee the issue, thank you!

Comment: Please validate the answer then ;) good continuation